# How to successfully integrate API documentation into your build process

Tags: continuous-integration, swagger, documentation, openapi

We've been looking into solutions to keep our API documentation accurate and up-to-date.  This has led me down this rabbit hole of various solutions using standards such as OpenAPI and a whole universe of open source tools for integrating API documentation into your build pipeline, setting up mock servers, failing the build when APIs change or no longer match the documentation, etc.  Right now, I'm fairly overwhelmed so to avoid having this question closed as "Too Broad", I'd like to narrow things down to a key piece of the puzzle that I'm a bit lost on.  In simple terms, how do you connect the auto-generated Swagger JSON to the fully documented and detailed version of the spec (most likely as a bunch of YAML files and Markdown files)?

Right now, we have the ability to generate Swagger JSON based on our compiled code, but it's sparse and doesn't contain any information that can't be obtained through the code itself.  Obviously I'd want to fill in details such as longer descriptions of each API, sample code, etc.  From what I can tell, it's standard practice to generate your OpenAPI specs using a tool that can import directly from Swagger, then you use an editor (such as [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/)) to fill in all the details.  This gets bundled up as a bunch of YAML files, MD files, etc which get checked into Github, and then there's various tools that could build that into some portal for your users to go to (Redoc does this sort of thing).

However, how do changes to your original "auto-generated JSON" get merged into the "final product"?  My guess would be there's some build step that runs some sort of diff tool that compares the autogenerated JSON from the current build to the "published" OpenAPI spec and then somehow alerts the team if there's new APIs that have to be documented or existing APIs that have changed and need their documentation update.  Is this kinda on track or is there a big part I'm missing.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Very-very good question. Question from me: how do you generate Swagger JSON?

Comment: @PirrenCode - We use a library called [Swashbuckle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/)